# Asterisk call should be with peer, but gets trapped and stays local

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip, sip, telephony

I'm working with Asterisk and Vicidial, trying to place outbound calls through a SIP "trunking" provider.  The calls never connect, instead I hear either demo-instruct.gsm or invalid.gsm playing from Asterisk.

I replaced the phone number with 9876543210.

In the log, I see:

```
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3279] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]   == Starting Local/8600051@default-00000000;1 at default,919876543210,1 failed so falling back to exten 's'
```

What's happening there?  When it says it failed, what failed and why?  Is it dialing out with the SIP "trunking" peer?  The intention is to pass that phone number to the peer so that the peer can dial it on the PSTN.

log:

```
[Apr  8 23:37:00] NOTICE[2910] chan_iax2.c: Peer 'ASTloop' is now UNREACHABLE! Time: 0
[Apr  8 23:37:00] NOTICE[2950] chan_sip.c: Peer '201' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Apr  8 23:37:00] NOTICE[2950] chan_sip.c: Peer '200' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Apr  8 23:37:02] VERBOSE[2991] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:02] VERBOSE[2990] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:02] VERBOSE[2991] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:02] VERBOSE[2990] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:05] VERBOSE[3069] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:05]   == Manager 'updatecron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:05] VERBOSE[3090] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:05]   == Manager 'listencron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:07] VERBOSE[3106] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:07]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:07] VERBOSE[3106] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:37:07]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2931] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 'ASTloop' (AUTHENTICATED) at 127.0.0.1:23289
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2932] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 to '127.0.0.1', who sees us as 127.0.0.1:23289 with no messages waiting
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2935] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 'ASTblind' (AUTHENTICATED) at 127.0.0.1:33696
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2937] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 to '127.0.0.1', who sees us as 127.0.0.1:33696 with no messages waiting
[Apr  8 23:37:08] NOTICE[2941] chan_iax2.c: Peer 'ASTloop' is now REACHABLE! Time: 4
[Apr  8 23:37:08] NOTICE[2944] chan_iax2.c: Peer 'ASTblind' is now REACHABLE! Time: 3
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2899] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 'ASTplay' (AUTHENTICATED) at 127.0.0.1:62907
[Apr  8 23:37:08] VERBOSE[2900] chan_iax2.c: [Apr  8 23:37:08] -- Registered IAX2 to '127.0.0.1', who sees us as 127.0.0.1:62907 with no messages waiting
[Apr  8 23:37:08] NOTICE[2904] chan_iax2.c: Peer 'ASTplay' is now REACHABLE! Time: 1
[Apr  8 23:37:47] VERBOSE[2950] chan_sip.c: [Apr  8 23:37:47]     -- Registered SIP '200' at 192.168.0.24:5060
[Apr  8 23:37:47] VERBOSE[2950] chan_sip.c: [Apr  8 23:37:47] > Saved useragent "YATE/5.4.2" for peer 200
[Apr  8 23:37:47] NOTICE[2950] chan_sip.c: Peer '200' is now Reachable. (60ms / 2000ms)
[Apr  8 23:38:02] VERBOSE[3198] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:02] VERBOSE[3199] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:02] VERBOSE[3199] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:02] VERBOSE[3198] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:02]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:07] VERBOSE[3212] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:07]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:07] VERBOSE[3212] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:07]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:39] VERBOSE[3256] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:39]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:39] VERBOSE[3256] netsock2.c: [Apr  8 23:38:39]   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3256] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]        > Channel SIP/200-00000000 was answered.
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]     -- Executing [8600051@default:1] MeetMe("SIP/200-00000000", "8600051,F") in new stack
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] config.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/meetme.conf': [Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] config.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]   == Found
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] config.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/meetme-vicidial.conf': [Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] config.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]   == Found
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] app_meetme.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41] -- Created MeetMe conference 1023 for conference '8600051'
[Apr  8 23:38:41] VERBOSE[3260] file.c: [Apr  8 23:38:41]     -- <SIP/200-00000000> Playing 'conf-onlyperson.gsm' (language 'en')
[Apr  8 23:38:41] WARNING[3260] res_rtp_asterisk.c: RTP Read too short
[Apr  8 23:38:42] VERBOSE[3256] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:42]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3277] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3278] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]     -- Executing [8600051@default:1] MeetMe("Local/8600051@default-00000000;2", "8600051,F") in new stack
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3277] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]        > Channel Local/8600051@default-00000000;1 was answered.
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3279] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]   == Starting Local/8600051@default-00000000;1 at default,919876543210,1 failed so falling back to exten 's'
[Apr  8 23:38:52] VERBOSE[3279] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:38:52]     -- Executing [s@default:1] wait("Local/8600051@default-00000000;1", "1")
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3279] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]     -- Executing [s@default:1] answer("Local/8600051@default-00000000;1", "")
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3279] func_timeout.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]     -- Digit timeout set to 5.000
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3279] func_timeout.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]     -- Response timeout set to 10.000
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3279] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]     -- Executing [s@default:1] background("Local/8600051@default-00000000;1", "demo-congrats")
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3277] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:38:53] VERBOSE[3279] file.c: [Apr  8 23:38:53]     -- <Local/8600051@default-00000000;1> Playing 'demo-congrats.gsm' (language 'en')
[Apr  8 23:39:03] VERBOSE[3321] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:03]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:03] VERBOSE[3322] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:03]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:03] VERBOSE[3322] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:03]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:03] VERBOSE[3321] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:03]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3338] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3278] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]   == Spawn extension (default, 8600051, 1) exited non-zero on 'Local/8600051@default-00000000;2'
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3278] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]     -- Executing [h@default:1] AGI("Local/8600051@default-00000000;2", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----0---------------") in new stack
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3278] res_agi.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]     -- <Local/8600051@default-00000000;2>AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----0--------------- completed, returning 0
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3279] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]   == Spawn extension (default, s, 1) exited non-zero on 'Local/8600051@default-00000000;1'
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3279] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]     -- Executing [h@default:1] AGI("Local/8600051@default-00000000;1", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----0---------------") in new stack
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3340] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:05] VERBOSE[3279] res_agi.c: [Apr  8 23:39:05]     -- <Local/8600051@default-00000000;1>AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----0--------------- completed, returning 0
[Apr  8 23:39:06] VERBOSE[3338] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:06] VERBOSE[3340] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:06]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:08] VERBOSE[3347] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:08]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:08] VERBOSE[3347] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:08]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:11] VERBOSE[3359] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:11]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged on from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:11] VERBOSE[3360] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:11]     -- Executing [8600051@default:1] MeetMe("Local/8600051@default-00000001;2", "8600051,F") in new stack
[Apr  8 23:39:11] VERBOSE[3359] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:11]        > Channel Local/8600051@default-00000001;1 was answered.
[Apr  8 23:39:11] VERBOSE[3361] pbx.c: [Apr  8 23:39:11]   == Starting Local/8600051@default-00000001;1 at default,91919876543210,1 failed so falling back to exten 's'
[Apr  8 23:39:11] VERBOSE[3361] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:39:11]     -- Executing [s@default:1] wait("Local/8600051@default-00000001;1", "1")
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3359] manager.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]   == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3361] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]     -- Executing [s@default:1] answer("Local/8600051@default-00000001;1", "")
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3361] func_timeout.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]     -- Digit timeout set to 5.000
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3361] func_timeout.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]     -- Response timeout set to 10.000
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3361] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]     -- Executing [s@default:1] background("Local/8600051@default-00000001;1", "demo-congrats")
[Apr  8 23:39:12] VERBOSE[3361] file.c: [Apr  8 23:39:12]     -- <Local/8600051@default-00000001;1> Playing 'demo-congrats.gsm' (language 'en')
[Apr  8 23:39:40] VERBOSE[3361] pbx_lua.c: [Apr  8 23:39:40]     -- Executing [s@default:1] background("Local/8600051@default-00000001;1", "demo-instruct")
[Apr  8 23:39:40] VERBOSE[3361] file.c: [Apr  8 23:39:40]     -- <Local/8600051@default-00000001;1> Playing 'demo-instruct.gsm' (language 'en')
vici:~ #
```

peers, where the context for babytel_out is defined as trunkinbound -- surely incorrect.  Why is it using that context?

```
vici:~ #
vici:~ # asterisk -rx "sip show peers"
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status    
200/200                   192.168.0.24                             D   N             64965    OK (35 ms)
201/201                   192.168.0.24                             D   N             5060     OK (38 ms)
202/202                   (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        UNKNOWN    
babytel_in                198.38.7.34                                  N             5065     OK (84 ms)
babytel_out/19876543210   198.38.7.34                                  N             5065     OK (85 ms)
gs102/gs102               (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        UNKNOWN    
6 sip peers [Monitored: 4 online, 2 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 0 offline]
vici:~ #
vici:~ # asterisk -rx "sip show peer babytel_out"


 * Name       : babytel_out
 Secret       : <Set>
 MD5Secret    : <Not set>
 Remote Secret: <Not set>
 Context      : trunkinbound
 Subscr.Cont. : <Not set>
 Language     : en
 AMA flags    : Unknown
 Netborder CPD: No
 Transfer mode: open
 CallingPres  : Presentation Allowed, Not Screened
 Callgroup    :
 Pickupgroup  :
 MOH Suggest  : default
 Mailbox      :
 VM Extension : asterisk
 LastMsgsSent : 32767/65535
 Call limit   : 0
 Max forwards : 0
 Dynamic      : No
 Callerid     : "" <>
 MaxCallBR    : 384 kbps
 Expire       : -1
 Insecure     : invite
 Force rport  : Yes
 ACL          : No
 DirectMedACL : No
 T.38 support : No
 T.38 EC mode : Unknown
 T.38 MaxDtgrm: 4294967295
 DirectMedia  : No
 PromiscRedir : No
 User=Phone   : No
 Video Support: No
 Text Support : No
 Ign SDP ver  : No
 Trust RPID   : No
 Send RPID    : Yes
 TrustIDOutbnd: Legacy
 Subscriptions: Yes
 Overlap dial : No
 Outb. proxy  : nat5.babytel.ca
 DTMFmode     : rfc2833
 Timer T1     : 500
 Timer B      : 32000
 ToHost       : nat5.babytel.ca
 Addr->IP     : 198.38.7.34:5065
 Defaddr->IP  : (null)
 Prim.Transp. : UDP
 Allowed.Trsp : UDP
 Def. Username: 19876543210
 SIP Options  : (none)
 Codecs       : 0x6 (gsm|ulaw)
 Codec Order  : (ulaw:20,gsm:20)
 Auto-Framing : No
 Status       : OK (85 ms)
 Useragent    :
 Reg. Contact :
 Qualify Freq : 60000 ms
 Sess-Timers  : Accept
 Sess-Refresh : uas
 Sess-Expires : 1800 secs
 Min-Sess     : 90 secs
 RTP Engine   : asterisk
 Parkinglot   :
 Use Reason   : No
 Encryption   : No

vici:~ #
```

contexts:

```
; WARNING- THIS FILE IS AUTO-GENERATED BY VICIDIAL, ANY EDITS YOU MAKE WILL BE LOST
register => 19876543210@sip.babytel.ca:huihylku6786ghjkghjk:19876543210@nat5.babytel.ca:5065/19876543210

; VICIDIAL Carrier: BABYTEL - babytel
; Babytel
[babytel_in]
type=peer
qualify=yes
host=nat5.babytel.ca
port=5065
context=inbound-calls


[babytel_out]
type=peer
username=19876543210
host=nat5.babytel.ca
outboundproxy=nat5.babytel.ca:5065
secret=huihylku6786ghjkghjk
canreinvite=no
insecure=invite
qualify=yes



[200]
username=200
secret=password
accountcode=200
callerid="" <200>
mailbox=200
context=default
type=friend
host=dynamic

[201]
username=201
secret=password
accountcode=201
callerid="" <201>
mailbox=201
context=default
type=friend
host=dynamic

[202]
username=202
secret=password
accountcode=202
callerid="" <202>
mailbox=202
context=default
type=friend
host=dynamic

[gs102]
username=gs102
secret=password
accountcode=gs102
callerid="Test Admin Phone" <>
mailbox=102
context=default
type=friend
host=dynamic


; END OF FILE    Last Forced System Reload: 2015-04-03 17:14:22
```

extensions:

```
; WARNING- THIS FILE IS AUTO-GENERATED BY VICIDIAL, ANY EDITS YOU MAKE WILL BE LOST
TRUNKloop = IAX2/ASTloop:password@127.0.0.1:40569
TRUNKblind = IAX2/ASTblind:password@127.0.0.1:41569
TRUNKplay = IAX2/ASTplay:password@127.0.0.1:42569
BABY = SIP/babytel_out



; agent phones restricted to only internal extensions
[default---agent]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,AGI(agi-VDAD_inbound_calltime_check.agi,-----NO-----default---agent-------------------------NO)
exten => s,n,Set(INVCOUNT=0)
exten => s,n,Background(sip-silence)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(20)


; hangup
exten => t,1,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => t,n,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Goto(s,4)
exten => i,n,Hangup()
; hangup
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})

; custom dialplan entries
include => vicidial-auto-internal
include => vicidial-auto-phones




; logging of all outbound calls from agent phones
[defaultlog]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,AGI(agi-VDAD_inbound_calltime_check.agi,-----NO-----defaultlog-------------------------NO)
exten => s,n,Set(INVCOUNT=0)
exten => s,n,Background(sip-silence)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(20)


; hangup
exten => t,1,Playback(vm-goodbye)
exten => t,n,Hangup()
exten => i,1,Goto(s,4)
exten => i,n,Hangup()
; hangup
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})

; custom dialplan entries
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi-NVA_recording.agi,BOTH------Y---Y---Y)
exten => _X.,n,Goto(default,${EXTEN},1)




[vicidial-auto-external]
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})

; Local Server: 192.168.0.19
exten => _192*168*000*019*.,1,Goto(default,${EXTEN:16},1)
exten => _192*168*000*019*.,2,Hangup()
exten => _**192*168*000*019*.,1,Goto(default,${EXTEN:18},1)
exten => _**192*168*000*019*.,2,Hangup()

; Agent session audio playback meetme entry
exten => _473782178600XXX,1,Meetme(${EXTEN:8},q)
exten => _473782178600XXX,n,Hangup()
; Agent session audio playback loop
exten => _473782168600XXX,1,Dial(${TRUNKplay}/47378217${EXTEN:8},5,To)
exten => _473782168600XXX,n,Hangup()
; Agent session audio playback extension
exten => 473782158521111,1,Answer
exten => 473782158521111,n,ControlPlayback(${CALLERID(name)},99999,0,1,2,3,4)
exten => 473782158521111,n,Hangup()
; SendDTMF to playback channel to control it
exten => _473782148521111.,1,Answer
exten => _473782148521111.,n,SendDTMF(${CALLERID(num)},250,250,IAX2/ASTplay-${EXTEN:15})
exten => _473782148521111.,n,Hangup()
; Silent wait channel for DTMFsend
exten => 473782138521111,1,Answer
exten => 473782138521111,n,Wait(5)
exten => 473782138521111,n,Hangup()
; VICIDIAL Carrier: BABYTEL - babytel
; Babytel
[general]
exten => _NXXXNxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _Nxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _1NXXNxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _011.,1,Dial(Dial({TOLL}/${EXTEN})
exten => _9NXXXNxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _9Nxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _91NXXNxxxxxx,1,Dial(${BABY}/${EXTEN})
exten => _9011.,1,Dial(Dial({TOLL}/${EXTEN})




[inbound-calls]
exten => 19876543210,1,Dial(SIP/200)

[local_200]
exten => _9x.,1,Set(CALLERID(all)="Ali Baba" <9876543210>)
exten => _9x.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:1}@babytel_out)
exten => 201,1,Dial(SIP/201)

[local_201]
exten => 200,1,Dial(SIP/200)

[vicidial-auto-internal]
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})
; Voicemail Extensions:
exten => _85026666666666.,1,Wait(1)
exten => _85026666666666.,n,Voicemail(${EXTEN:14},u)
exten => _85026666666666.,n,Hangup()
exten => _85026666666667.,1,Wait(1)
exten => _85026666666667.,n,Voicemail(${EXTEN:14},su)
exten => _85026666666667.,n,Hangup()
exten => 8500,1,VoicemailMain
exten => 8500,2,Goto(s,6)
exten => 8500,3,Hangup()
exten => 8501,1,VoicemailMain(s${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 8501,2,Hangup()

; Prompt Extensions:
exten => 8167,1,Answer
exten => 8167,2,AGI(agi-record_prompts.agi,wav-----720000)
exten => 8167,3,Hangup()
exten => 8168,1,Answer
exten => 8168,2,AGI(agi-record_prompts.agi,gsm-----720000)
exten => 8168,3,Hangup()

; this is used for recording conference calls, the client app sends the filename
;    value as a callerID recordings go to /var/spool/asterisk/monitor (WAV)
;    Recording is limited to 1 hour, to make longer, just change the server
;    setting ViciDial Recording Limit
;     this is the WAV verison, default
exten => 8309,1,Answer
exten => 8309,2,Monitor(wav,${CALLERID(name)})
exten => 8309,3,Wait(3600)
exten => 8309,4,Hangup()
;     this is the GSM verison
exten => 8310,1,Answer
exten => 8310,2,Monitor(gsm,${CALLERID(name)})
exten => 8310,3,Wait(3600)
exten => 8310,4,Hangup()

;     agent alert extension
exten => 83047777777777,1,Answer
exten => 83047777777777,2,Playback(${CALLERID(name)})
exten => 83047777777777,3,Hangup()
; This is a loopback dial-around to allow for immediate answer of outbound calls
exten => _8305888888888888.,1,Answer
exten => _8305888888888888.,n,Wait(${EXTEN:16:1})
exten => _8305888888888888.,n,Dial(${TRUNKloop}/${EXTEN:17},,To)
exten => _8305888888888888.,n,Hangup()
; No-call silence extension
exten => _8305888888888888X999,1,Answer
exten => _8305888888888888X999,n,Wait(3600)
exten => _8305888888888888X999,n,Hangup()

[vicidial-auto-phones]
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})

; Phones direct dial extensions:
exten => 200,1,Dial(SIP/200,60,)
exten => 200,2,Goto(default,85026666666666200,1)
exten => 200,3,Hangup()
exten => 201,1,Dial(SIP/201,60,)
exten => 201,2,Goto(default,85026666666666201,1)
exten => 201,3,Hangup()
exten => 202,1,Dial(SIP/202,60,)
exten => 202,2,Goto(default,85026666666666202,1)
exten => 202,3,Hangup()
exten => 102,1,Dial(SIP/gs102,60,)
exten => 102,2,Goto(default,85026666666666102,1)
exten => 102,3,Hangup()

[vicidial-auto]
exten => h,1,AGI(agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----${HANGUPCAUSE}-----${DIALSTATUS}-----${DIALEDTIME}-----${ANSWEREDTIME})

include => vicidial-auto-internal
include => vicidial-auto-phones
include => vicidial-auto-external


; END OF FILE    Last Forced System Reload: 2015-04-03 17:14:22
```

see also:

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/DeviceConfig_id216341.html

Answer (score 1):

try to rename

```
; Babytel
[general]
```

to

```
; Babytel
[default]
```

Comment: Adding detail on why this would be the answer would improve this.

Answer (score 1):

It says *failed* because it is failed to find this extension in the given context.

According to your sip.conf default context for your SIP users is *default*, but all patterns that can handle 919876543210 are in *general* context. So Asterisk can't find them when you placing a call since the call flow doesn't go through *general* context.

You probably want to set *general* as context for your SIP users.